# how to check in python if there is any even number in list

Tags: python

I am a newbie who just start learning python. here is my list:

```
list1 = [3,105,97,17,68241,5,3,8,]
```

how I will check if there is any even number in my list

Comment: This is simple enough. Can you show us where you got stuck?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far, aka your loop etc. or see [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try and identify what makes a number even. In your head, what could you do to the number to prove it is even? You divide it by 2 and see if the remainder is 0. In programming, we use the modulo operator (%) to get the remainder of an equation.

Try and think of a way that you can iterate over the items in your list and see if they are even using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python builtin function which name is any(). here is my code which will check if your list have any even number. You will get true value if there is any even number in your list otherwise it will return false.

```
list1 = [3,105,97,17,68241,5,3,8,]
print(any(num%2 == 0 for num in list1))
```

Comment: Thanks Farhan. You answered exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer, but @Joe perhaps as a beginner you should try and do some research. This isn't that hard of a problem and it would be simple to google, which could build your understanding for the future